# Do the subject and object have to agree in number? For example: "Tigers (plural) are a wild animal (singular)"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, grammatical-number, subjects, objects

Does the plurality of the object have to agree with the plurality of the subject? For example, which one of the following sentences is correct?

- Tigers are **wild animals** and they live in the jungle.
- Tigers are **a wild animal** and they live in the jungle.

and similarly,

- Sports are **an important part** of the school curriculum.
- Sports are **important parts** of the school curriculum.

Comment: **Tigers are wild animals** or **The tiger is a wild animal** (using the singular to mean 'a typical member of the species'). PS _Wild animal_ isn't an object here.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you for your correction of the wrong terminology. Can you provide a full answer to my question?

Comment: @KateBunting Hmmm. Says who?

Comment: It's a bit sloppy/informal, but [***Moles are a wild animal***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22moles+are+a+wild+animal%22) is *just about* acceptable to me. I don't recommend learners to *copy* the usage, but they shouldn't assume if a native speaker uses it, he's just making a mistake. The writer of my linked example looks *very* articulate to me - I certainly wouldn't want to find fault with his command of English.

Comment: Side note, in British English you wouldn't say sports, rather  "Sport is..."

Comment: @Chenmunka - that's not an absolute rule.

Comment: There are no absolute rules.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly, great minds. See my post below.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. - Re: your comments in your answer - I didn't say that anything was wrong or nonsense, I just gave the two versions that seemed most idiomatic to me.

Comment: @ASlowLearner - I think most people would consider sport[s], grouped together as a type of activity, to be one part of the curriculum, rather than each sport as a separate part.

Comment: @KateBunting Ah, I took your comment to be a correction, implying the original was ungrammatical. The other descriptions are from another answers. Howabout I edit my answer and you recast your comment?

Comment: Perhaps we should also note (for the questioner) that the verb "to be" (... "are"...) behaves differently from verbs that _do_ take direct and indirect objects. So, as @KateBunting says, "wild animals" is not exactly a "direct object"...

Comment: Depends on formality. As per answers, you'll see plenty of people "breaking" this "rule," but it will seem less polished. This will be particularly common in spoken language (or casual registers that mimic spoken language), because you can't take back words you've already said. So it's a common experience to start a sentence one way, and realize later that the most comfortable phrasing for the complement doesn't match the number of the subject you used. Native speakers will just go with the flow here.

Comment: Those are *subject complements*, not objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, subjects and complements do not have to agree in number. Objects, which are a special type of complement, do not need to either.

Examples:

1. This penguin likes tigers. <sup>*Singular subject, plural object*</sup>
2. People love this book. <sup>*Plural subject, singular object*</sup>
3. Tigers are an endangered species. <sup>*Plural subject, singular complement*</sup>
4. The problem is the mice. <sup>*Singular subject, plural complement*</sup>

Some users here have said in answers that the sentence *Tigers are a wild animal* is incorrect, or that it does not make sense, or that it is not true. They are mistaken. The sentence is perfectly grammatical and perfectly natural. I would prefer *Tigers are wild animals*, but what I prefer is not important, and I don't expect or want anyone to take any notice of it!

Here are some real examples from the web:

- Tigers are a fascinating, and endangered, animal. [<sup>1</sup>](https://www.bartleby.com/essay/Tigers-P3JNPEZYTC)
- Well-known for their distinct orange and black striped coats, tigers are a popular animal to see at the Zoo. [<sup>2</sup>](https://nationalzoo.si.edu/animals/news/how-care-for-tigers)
- Tigers are a popular animal in mythology and pop culture. [<sup>3</sup>](https://a-z-animals.com/blog/tiger-spirit-animal-symbolism-meaning/)
- Nowadays tigers are a rare animal, so, the cost of one tiger is much higher than 50 years ago.[<sup>4</sup>](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/294261456_Why_are_Wild_Tigers_in_danger)
- Tigers are a seriously endangered animal.[<sup>5</sup>](https://owlconnected.com/archives/tigers-kazakhstan)
- The constituents and effect are very similar to tiger bone, the use of which is prohibited because tigers are a protected animal in China.[<sup>6</sup>](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/os.12439)

One of those links is from a peer reviewed research paper. So, it does not matter whether users here think this is good style or not, it is perfectly grammatical. Many expert native speakers say, write and publish sentences like these every day.

Comment: One good thing about ***species*** is that (like ***sheep***) the singular and plural are the same. Anyway, there's obviously no problem with *Tigers are an endangered species*, but even though you might occasionally encounter *Tigers are an endangered animal* from a competent native Anglophone, I don't think it's a good idea to give *learners* the impression there's no difference in idiomacy between that and the far more common "consistent" phrasings *Tigers are endangered animals* and *The tiger is an endangered animal*

Comment: I agree, but I reckon OP is not at that kind of level where they're going to be saying weird sentences on account of this query. They're dabbling around with "curriculum" and the like, so I think they'll be fine. I'd hazard they've come across this sentence and want to check that it's not a grammar mistake.

Comment: Yes, but this particular OP specialises in finding "counterexamples" that appear to conflict with what dictionaries or textbooks say. Which may be because they conflate "idiomatically commonplace" usage notes with "syntactically required" formats, OR because precious few "syntax rules" really are "unbreakable" to all competent native speakers in all contexts (even though most learners would be well advised to understand and respect those rules themselves *all the time*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers can you elaborate the idiomacy difference between "tigers are an endangered animal", "tigers are endangered animals", and "the tiger is an endangered animal"?

Comment: @ASlowLearner: The difference is simply that the "plurality clash" version "tigers are an endangered animal" is *relatively* uncommon, and you can see for yourself that at least *some* perfectly competent native speakers are saying it's either invalid or they don't like it. But me and Araucaria are saying it's not actually invalid. He may or may not agree with me that even though we don't think it's "invalid", I strongly recommend you not to use that format yourself. Just don't assume that any native Anglophone who does so does so out of ignorance! As to the other two versions, they're fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you so much for all your help and patience!

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps to make an "appeal to authority" by saying one of the examples comes from a peer-reviewed paper. There's no reason to suppose that an authority on Tigers is also an authority on how to write good English.

Comment: @DominicCronin The main reasons for mentioning peer-reviewed, published papers are that they are expected to be written in formal and proper academic English (no claim here that formal=proper, far from it), secondly they are peer reviewed and also edited by the journal, and the vast majority of any slips and  errors, in any journal worth its salt are picked up at this stage before the paper is published. In contrast, it is more likely that a personal blog or a mere comment on the web contains slips and errors which haven't been pulled out by a reviewer or proofreader. They could just be slips.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. One of the links has been uploaded to researchgate by the author, and even has a doi, but that doesn't make it peer-reviewed. Indeed, it is a high-school project from a Portuguese school. I imagine English (rather than tigers) is the subject being studied, but understandably the grammar is not perfect.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Sorry, looks like I missed it off. It's (6) above, from *Orthopedic Surgery* 11(2):176-186. Thanks. See, the benefits of peer review triumph again!

Comment: I get what you are saying but I'm not sure this always holds.  Would you consider: "Alice and Bob are interesting person" to be a grammatical phrase?  How about "Interstates are widely-used road"?

Comment: @JimmyJames Both your examples require a determiner (a word like *a[n], the, some, any, no, my* etc). Even after that's fixed, finding a good use for the first would be difficult, but *interstates are a widely-used road* is ok if what's meant is a widely used type of road, i.e. where *road* is generic. The first is grammatical ,but would need a specific context to make sense. (1/2)

Comment: @JimmyJames For example, if they were students in a history class where each group had to write a speech as a famous person from history, it would be reasonable to say "Jill and Dave are Winston Churchill, Dave and Javi are Sigmund Freud. Oh, and Alice and Bob are an interesting person; they're Che Guevara" Or something like that. You can see how it might go. :) (2/2)

Comment: You make some good points.  I suppose there's a difference between being grammatical and making sense.  The latter depends on the context.  For example, 'bricks are material' and 'bricks are a material' are both grammatical but have distinctly different meanings.  Which one makes sense depends on what you are trying to communicate.  "Tigers are a wild animal" works here but I think it would be misleading to suggest that such alternate phrasing is always equivalent even if grammatical.

Comment: @JimmyJames "You make some good points." <--- I ought to, I'm a fletcher.

Answer (score 7):

No, the subject and object of a verb don't have to agree:

> A man eats some chips.

The subject (man) is singular and the object (chips) is plural.

In your example, you don't have an object, but a complement, and the verb is a linking verb.  Again the subject and complement don't have to agree, but they often do.

In the case of the "tigers" example you would use the plural. It is not correct to say that "Tigers are a wild animal." No grammar rule has been broken, but it simply isn't true! It is true to say that "Tigers are wild animals."

In the second example, it is very natural to say "Sports are a part..." The many sports are one part of the curriculum.  That is true.

It is easy to make other examples:

> The people are a team.

> My family is all men.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: "No grammar rule has been broken, but it simply isn't true!" I'm not sure if this is the case? From a literal perspective yeah, but I think there's a subtle kind of metonymy going on there. Like, I think it's too low-level to even call it a metaphor, but at least to me it parses as though there's just some kind of idiomatic abstraction happening where the singular complement gets implicitly mapped to all members of the group individually.

Answer (score 0):

Each tiger is a separate wild animal (and the species is a single line in the list of different types of wild animals), but each sport can be considered a smaller part of a big important part of the school curriculum.

Answer (score 0):

In the examples provided by the OP the verb connecting subject and object is "are". In that special case I would always *expect* agreement, and similarly for all similar cases such as "is", "were", "might become" and so on (I am uncertain how to describe them collectively) For other types of connecting verb, as many examples show, there is no reason to expect agreement.